# Change syntax highlighting in RST-Sphinx documentation

Tags: css, themes, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm writing documentation in RST and generating HTML with Sphinx.

In the code examples, the command we want the user to enter is italicized by default - is there a way to make this code bold?

For example::

```
ACOS# this is some text that is currently italics but i would like it to be bold
```

I'm using sphinx-rtd-theme, and the markup is `::` followed by the code. Using Sphinx 1.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character causes the text after it to be interpreted as a comment. It is rendered in italics by default. The CSS rule is in pygments.css (located in `_static` in the output directory):

```
.highlight .c { color: #408090; font-style: italic } /* Comment */
```

If you want to change this to bold, the rule should be:

```
.highlight .c { color: #408090; font-weight: bold } /* Comment */
```

To make this happen, you can do as follows:

1. Copy the default pygments.css file to the `_static` folder in your Sphinx project.
2. Change the CSS rule as above.
3. Regenerate the project output. Your customized pygments.css will now be used instead of the default one.

---

Here is another way to do it that works with sphinx-rtd-theme.

1. Create a file called mystyle.css and put it in the `_static` directory of your project.
2. Add this line to conf.py (see http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-html_style):

   ```
   html_style = 'mystyle.css'
   ```
3. Add the following to mystyle.css:

   ```
   @import "css/theme.css";

   .highlight .c { font-weight: bold; font-style: normal  } /* Comment */
   ```

Comment: I made the change in the source/_static/pygments.css, but the font continues to be italic. Once i remove the hash the text in the code block changes to normal text. Can you please help troubleshoot?

Comment: It appears that sphinx-rtd-theme works differently from most other themes. It does not use pygments.css. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx_rtd_theme#contributing-or-modifying-the-theme.

Comment: changed .highlight .c to .highlight.c1 and it worked. Thanks a lot!